# Pig Accumulator, are input tuples guaranteed to be ordered?

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig

I wrote a UDF that implements the `Accumulator` interface. However, for my UDF to work, the incoming relation needs to be sorted. I'm managing this with a secondary sort:

```
out = FOREACH (GROUP test BY key) {
    sorted = ORDER test BY sub_key;
    GENERATE MyUDF(sorted);
}
```

Per the `Accumulator` docs, my UDF is expecting a series of incremental bags. Is the total order in which my UDF receives tuples maintained? I.e. is each incremental bag internally ordered, and is the sequence I see incremental bags ordered?

Everything seems to be ordered when I test it, but I'd like to be sure since the Pig docs describe bags as "unordered".

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used ORDER operator to sort the tuples inside a bag, your UDF would receive the tuples inside the 'sorted' bag ordered for sure.